# error en un ejercicio de clase

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Debo realizar un programa que lea de la entrada del usuario los siguientes datos sobre una persona:

- Edad: tipo entero.
- Sexo: tipo carácter.
- Altura: tipo real.

Tras leer los datos, el programa debe mostrarlos en la salida. Tengo esto:

```
/*Despues de esta linea incluya la solucion. Recuerde agregar nombre y grupo*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    
    int edad;
    char sexo[10];
    float altura;
    cout<<"Cuantos años tienes:";cin>>edad;
    cout<<"Cual es su sexo:";cin>>sexo;
    cout<<"Cuanto mides";cin>>altura;
    return 0;
}
```

Mi problema es que me dice esto todo junto Digite edad:Digite su sexo:Digite la altura en metros:
[Program exited with exit code 0]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yo tambien estoy aprendiendo c++. A tu programa le pasa eso porque no tiene un espaciado. Pero eso se puede solcuionar con endl. eso es un salto de linea con que se encuentra en la iostream. Si lo usas sirve para hacer mas estetica los resultados y los datos que se imprimen en tu programa mediante COUT

Yo lo uso bastabte en mis programas. Si lo usas en el tuyo se queda #include

```
<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int edad;
    char sexo[10];
    float altura;
    cout<<"Cuantos años tienes:";cin>>edad;
    cout<<"Cual es su sexo:";cin>>sexo;
    cout<<"Cuanto mides";cin>>altura;
    cout<<"\ntu edad es:"<<edad<<endl;
    cout<<"\ntu sexo es:"<<sexo<<endl;
    cout<<"\ntu mides:"<<altura<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo porfin pude terminar este ejercicio en el que estaba atorado ahora si me dice bien los datos